How to fix tab bar item position?
I have a tabBar. And I want to change items position of tabBar. I trying to do this with using this code in TabBarController subclass:
override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidAppear(animated)
        let buttons = tabBar.subviews.filter { String(describing: type(of: $0)) == "UITabBarButton" }
        buttons.forEach {
            if let superviewHeight = $0.superview?.frame.height {
                $0.center = CGPoint(x: $0.frame.midX, y: superviewHeight * 0.5 - ((SafeArea().bottom()) * 0.5))
            }
        }
    }

or with this code:
override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidAppear(animated)
        for tabBarItem in (self.tabBar.items)!{
            let viewTabBar = tabBarItem.value(forKey: "view") as? UIView
            let  imgView = viewTabBar?.subviews[0] as? UIImageView
            viewTabBar?.frame.origin.y  = -13
            imgView?.clipsToBounds = true
            imgView?.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
        }
    }

But if I click on tabBarItem all return to default position. How to change it?

TabBar was designed always at the bottom. You will need a custom view that represents TabBar for this purpose.
